# Reading/Writing with System Calls

Tags: c

I'm trying to write code (in C) which will read from one file, and write to a created file. The only part I'm struggling with is the while loop, which is supposed to continuously read and write until the end of file. I get the first 120 characters, write them, then write 'XYZ' to the file, but when I try to read/write again, I get ^@ and a bunch of garbage. I don't want a solution on how to do this, just tell me what I am doing wrong/forgot to do.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
  int a, b, c;
  int XYZ = creat("XYZ.doc", 777);
  if(XYZ<0) {
    printf("error with creat");
    exit(0);
  }
  int xxxx = open("/usr/class/cis660/xx.xx", 0);
  if(xxxx<0) {
    printf("error with open");
    exit(0);
  }
  int tryread = 1;
  int trywrite;
  while (tryread > 0) {
    char buffer[120];
    tryread = read(xxxx, &buffer, 120);
    trywrite = write(XYZ, &buffer, 120);
    char xyz[3] = "XYZ";
    trywrite = write(XYZ, &xyz, 120);
  }
}
```

Comment: Use the return value from read() and write(); they can be different from 120. BTW: main() shall return int. plus: `int XYZ = creat("XYZ.doc", 0777);` (0777 is octal)

Comment: Note that neither Standard C nor Microsoft C supports `void main()`; it should be `int main(void)` and if you are dealing with C89 (MSVC) you must `return 0;` or something similar.  Even with C99 or C11, it is (IMO) better to include the return at the end of `main()`.

Answer (score 7):

> ```
> char xyz[3] = "XYZ";
> trywrite = write(XYZ, &xyz, 120);
> ```

This is your main problem. You are trying to write 120, when you only have 3. You have other problems:

- **you are not checking what `read` and `write` return**
- `read` and `write` don't return `int`, but `ssize_t`
- `open(path, 0)` works, but you should use `O_RDONLY`
- you are using `void main` instead of the correct `int main`
- as Jonathan Leffler pointed out, you should use `buffer` instead of `&buffer`

Comment: `int` will hold a `ssize_t` values when the size of the buffer is `120` bytes.  You might need to worry if you do 2 GiB writes...

Comment: Thanks! I'm an idiot. Trying to learn System Calls on my feet is really challenging.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, I was being pedantic :-))

Answer (score 3):

Your loop should only try to write as many bytes as it read:

```
int nread;
char buffer[120];
while ((nread = read(xxxx, buffer, sizeof(buffer)) > 0)
    int nwritten = write(XYZ, buffer, nread);
    if (nwritten != nread)
        ...short write error...
    char xyz[3] = "XYZ"; // Not a null terminated string
    nwritten = write(XYZ, xyz, sizeof(xyz));
    // ...check this write too
}
```

Note that the code does not, and should not, use `&buffer` and `&xyz`, unlike the code in the question.  The original code tried to write using data from way beyond the end of the `xyz` array; it also did not properly handle short writes, and would write the last buffer full a second time when it gets EOF.

Comment: Using `&buffer` is actually ok in this instance (assuming the other errors are corrected), because the address of an array is numerically equal to the address of its first element, but it's of a different type; but since `read(2)` and `write(2)` take `void*`/`const void*` arguments, that doesn't matter.  If `*printf(3)`/`*scanf(3)` were being used, however, then you'd technically get undefined behavior, since the C language standard says that you must pass arguments of the correct type, i.e. a `char*`/`const char*` with the `%s` format specifier.

Comment: Yes, with the arrays, you're right — the (byte) address of the array is also the (byte) address of the first element of the array, but the types are different, as you say.  If, however, one of the arrays was a function argument, or a `char *`, then using the `&` would give the wrong result. IMNSHO, it is better to head off the problem before it starts than to recognize that this special case works but other cases don't.

Comment: Agreed, in cases like this where they're equivalent, it's definitely better to just use `buffer` instead of `&buffer`, since the former is more likely to be correct in the general case.  In fact, I think that taking the address of an array is an exceedingly rarely needed operation that should only be used in special situations, like iterating through the rows of a 2D matrix with pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

change this you are writing 120 bytes instead of three bytes

```
trywrite = write(XYZ, &xyz, 120);  =>trywrite = write(XYZ, &xyz, 3);
```

Suggestion:remove declarations inside while loop you added declaration before while

```
  char buffer[120];
    char xyz[3] = "XYZ"; 
 while (tryread > 0) {

    tryread = read(xxxx, &buffer, 120);
    trywrite = write(XYZ, &buffer, 120);

    trywrite = write(XYZ, &xyz, 120);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The garbage is due to 120 bytes you are trying to write to XYZ for which you are actually writing 3 chars